# Converting Spark Dataframe(with WrappedArray) to RDD[labelPoint] in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, dataframe, rdd

I am new to Scala and I want to convert dataframe to rdd. let the  **label, features** convert to `RDD[labelPoint]` for the input of MLlib. But I can't find out the way to deal with `WrappedArray`.

```
scala> test.printSchema
root
 |-- user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- brand_store_sn: string (nullable = true)
 |-- label: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- money_score: double (nullable = true)
 |-- normal_score: double (nullable = true)
 |-- action_score: double (nullable = true)
 |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- flag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dt: string (nullable = true)


scala> test.head
res21: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [2533,10005072,1,2.0,1.0,1.0,WrappedArray(["d90_pv_1sec:1.4471580313422192", "d3_pv_1sec:0.9030899869919435", "d7_pv_1sec:0.9030899869919435", "d30_pv_1sec:1.414973347970818", "d90_pv_week_decay:1.4235871662780681", "d1_pv_1sec:0.9030899869919435", "d120_pv_1sec:1.4471580313422192"]),user_positive,20161130]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - since `LabeledPoint` expects a Vector of `Double`s, I'm assuming you also want to split each element in every `features` array by colon (`:`), and treat the right-hand side of it as the double, e.g.:

```
 "d90_pv_1sec:1.4471580313422192" --> 1.4471580313422192
```

If so - here's the transformation:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint

// sample data - DataFrame with label, features and other columns
val df = Seq(
  (1, Array("d90_pv_1sec:1.4471580313422192", "d3_pv_1sec:0.9030899869919435"), 4.0),
  (2, Array("d7_pv_1sec:0.9030899869919435", "d30_pv_1sec:1.414973347970818"), 5.0)
).toDF("label", "features", "ignored")

// extract relevant fields from Row and convert WrappedArray[String] into Vector:
val result = df.rdd.map(r => {
  val label = r.getAs[Int]("label")
  val featuresArray = r.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[String]]("features")
  val features: Vector = Vectors.dense(
    featuresArray.map(_.split(":")(1).toDouble).toArray
  )
  LabeledPoint(label, features)
})

result.foreach(println)
// (1.0,[1.4471580313422192,0.9030899869919435])
// (2.0,[0.9030899869919435,1.414973347970818])
```

**EDIT**: per clarification, now assuming each item in the input array contains the expected *index* in a resulting *sparse* vector:

```
"d90_pv_1sec:1.4471580313422192" --> index = 90; value = 1.4471580313422192
```

The modified code would be:

```
val vectorSize: Int = 100 // just a guess - should be the maximum index + 1

val result = df.rdd.map(r => {
  val label = r.getAs[Int]("label")
  val arr = r.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[String]]("features").toArray
  // parse each item into (index, value) tuple to use in sparse vector
  val elements = arr.map(_.split(":")).map {
    case Array(s, d) => (s.replaceAll("d|_pv_1sec","").toInt, d.toDouble)
  }
  LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.sparse(vectorSize, elements))
})

result.foreach(println)
// (1.0,(100,[3,90],[0.9030899869919435,1.4471580313422192]))
// (2.0,(100,[7,30],[0.9030899869919435,1.414973347970818]))
```

**NOTE**: Using `s.replaceAll("d|_pv_1sec","")` might be a bit slow, as it compiles a regular expression for each item separately. If that's the case, it can be replaced by the faster (yet uglier) `s.replace("d", "").replace("_pv_1sec", "")` which doesn't use regular expressions.

Comment: er...i want a  label and a sparse feature vector format like: LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.sparse(3, Array("d90_pv_1sec", "d3_pv_1sec"), Array(1.4471580313422192, 0.9030899869919435)))

Comment: You can't - `LabeledPoint.features`has type `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`, which is necessarily a vector of `Doubles` and not Strings/Arrays - see https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Vectors.scala#L41

Comment: if I make the feature hashing,how can I make that format?  casue the features is a  sparse array .   I want let it be :  LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.sparse(3, Array(1,1.4471580313422192 ), Array(2, 0.9030899869919435),Array(3, 0.9030899869919435)))

Comment: I don't follow - are you saying that for input `d7_pv_1sec:0.9030899869919435` the resulting sparse vector should contain the value `0.9030899869919435` in *index* `7`?

Comment: Yes,you got it.  My Data Source is a sparse vector .so I want to keep the index and the value.I can hashing the index from string to interger.

Comment: See edit. You should really by **MUCH** clearer in your question - specify the exact expected output for a given example input - I can't guess your requirements.

Comment: I make it by :LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.sparse(3,featuresArray.map(_.split(":")(0).toInt).toArray, featuresArray.map(_.split(":")(0).toDouble).toArray))