# Spark Dataframe of WrappedArray to Dataframe[Vector]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark Dataframe `df` with the following schema:

```java
root
 |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
```

I would like to create a new Dataframe where each row will be a Vector of `Double`s and expecting to get the following schema:

```java
root
     |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

So far I have the following piece of code (influenced by this post: [Converting Spark Dataframe(with WrappedArray) to RDD[labelPoint] in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377850/converting-spark-dataframewith-wrappedarray-to-rddlabelpoint-in-scala)) but I fear something is wrong with it because it takes a very long time to compute even a reasonable amount of rows.
Also, if there are too many rows the application will crash with a heap space exception.

```java
val clustSet = df.rdd.map(r => {
          val arr = r.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Double]]("features")
          val features: Vector = Vectors.dense(arr.toArray)
          features
          }).map(Tuple1(_)).toDF()
```

I suspect that the instruction `arr.toArray` is not a good Spark practice in this case. Any clarification would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `.rdd` have to unserialize objects from internal in-memory format and it is very time consuming.

It's ok to use `.toArray` - you are operating on row level, not collecting everything to the driver node.

You can do this very easy with UDFs:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg._
val convertUDF = udf((array : Seq[Double]) => {
  Vectors.dense(array.toArray)
})
val withVector = dataset
  .withColumn("features", convertUDF('features))
```

Code is from this answer: [Convert ArrayType(FloatType,false) to VectorUTD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43849898/convert-arraytypefloattype-false-to-vectorutd/43850143#43850143)

However there author of the question didn't ask about differences

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot and marked it as the answer. I can run more rows now and it is satisfying time-wise. I still get though an exception: __org.apache.spark.SparkException: Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow. Available: 0, required: 1__ when I try 200,000 rows. Would you have an insight about this? Thanks again.

Comment: @user159941 Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947335/how-kryo-serializer-allocates-buffer-in-spark

Comment: I set in my code the following: **val conf = new SparkConf()
      .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb","256")** and it worked! Thank you.